# Rope created with Bezier Curve has some color issues

Tags: materials

I created a rope with four circles, screw modifier and Bezier Curve, the color however acts strange? It's inconsistent. Any idea why? I use normal Principle BDSF shader. Second image, my modifiers since I don't really know what to show.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Topology was the issue, thanks ChatGPT. Issue was gone after changing "image A" to "image B"

[image]

[image]